# Scheme equivalent of print function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, scheme, racket

I'm looking at Scheme (Dr-Scheme) coming from Clojure.

In Clojure I can type

```
(print 'a 'b 'c)
```

and the `print` function figures out that this is an arbitrary number of non-string arguments and prints them out separated by a space.

In Scheme the `print` function expects a single argument.

Is there a way to get the equivalent of Clojure's print function in Scheme?

Comment: `fold` the values in a single string by concatenation with a space in between each word and call print ?

Comment: (If you're looking at "DrScheme", then you're looking at an outdated software...)

Comment: DrScheme is outdated? Perhaps you mean the active community support has moved to DrRacket. Arguably most of the interesting texts on Scheme are either during the DrScheme era or prior to it - but I wouldn't call them outdated.

Comment: In case this isn't clear: DrScheme and DrRacket are actually the same animal. Newer versions of DrScheme are called DrRacket. Apologies if you already knew that.

Comment: @hawkeye, software becomes outdated much more quickly than books.  But DrScheme is a special case -- it's just an older version of software that's now called by a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting... you can roll one of those pretty easily, but I'm not sure I see the need for it. For instance:

```
#lang racket

(define (print-many . args)
  (display
   (apply
    string-append
    (add-between (map print-to-string args) " "))))

(define (print-to-string arg) (format "~v" arg))

(print-many 3 4 5 'b '(3 3 4))
```

In general, though, I'm thinking that if you're generating output for a user, you're going to want better control over the output, and if you're not generating output for a user, you're just as happy slapping a pair of parens around it and making it into a list.

What's the use case for this?

Comment: Use case? Lots of things - the first one that comes to mind is printing function arguments.

Comment: right... so instead of typing (print arg1 arg2 arg3), you have to write (print (list arg1 arg2 arg3)).  That seems like a negligible cost, and you get a benefit as well, which is that you can see where the list ends.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for `trace` ?

```
#lang racket

(define (foo x y)
  (+ x y))

(define (bar x)
  (+ (foo 1 x)
     (foo 2 (+ x 1))))

(require racket/trace)
(trace foo)
```

And then in the interaction window:

```
> (bar 3)

>(foo 1 3)
<4
>(foo 2 4)
<6
10
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is about

Comment: You are probably right. It was this comment "Use case? Lots of things - the first one that comes to mind is printing function arguments." that made by associate to trace.

Comment: Hi Guys, Really appreciate this answer - it does fit into "the question behind the question" and I have been using this quite a lot - but sometimes I wanted a kind of "mid method argument dump" which is why I asked the question this way. Really appreciate the effort you put into this answer, and your thoughtfulness behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this set of definitions to print multiple arguments separated by new line:

```
(define (println x) (display x) (newline))
(define (printlist l) (begin
                        (println (car l))
                        (if (not (null? (cdr l))) (printlist (cdr l)))))  
(define (multiprint  . args) (begin
                                (if (not (null? args)) (printlist args) 
                                    (println "Error: multiprint requires at least one argument"))))
```

Comment: Wow +1 for non-racket dependencies (ie working in older versions of scheme). Is there a way we can just separate out the list items with spaces instead of newlines - and just have a newline at the end?